# Matching Word() when word is not (some word)

Tags: regex, vim

Specifically, I want to match functions in my Javascript code that are not in a set of common standard Javascript functions. In other words, I want to match user defined functions. I'm working with vim's flavour of regexp, but I don't mind seeing solutions for other flavours.

As I understand it, regexp crawls through a string character by character, so thinking in terms of sets of characters can be problematic even when a problem seems simple. I've tried negative lookahead, and as you might expect all the does is prevent the first character of the functions I don't want from being matched (ie, onsole.log instead of console.log).

`(?(?!(if)|(console\.log)|(function))\w+)\(.*\)`

> function(meep, boop, doo,do)
>
> JSON.parse(localStorage["beards"])
>
> console.log("sldkfjls" + dododo);
>
> if (beepboop) {
>
> BLAH.blah.somefunc(arge, arg,arg);

https://regexr.com/

I would like to be able to crawl through a function and see where it is calling other usermade functions. Will I need to do post-processing (ie mapping with another regexp) on the matches to reject matches I don't want, or is there a way to do this in one regexp?

Comment: Have you tried adding \< in front of the \w, to say it has to be the beginning of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic recipe for a regular expression that matches all words except `foo` (in Vim's regular expression syntax) is:

```
/\<\%(foo\>\)\@!\k\+\>/
```

Note how the negative lookahead (`\@!`) needs an end assertion (here: `\>`) on its own, to avoid that it also excludes anything that just *starts* with the expression!

Applied to your examples (excluding `if` (potentially with whitespace), `console.log`, and `function`, ending with `(`), that gives:

```
\<\%(\%(if *\|console\.log\|function\)(\)\@!\(\k\|\.\)\+\>(.*)
```

As you seem to want to include the entire object chain (so `JSON.parse` instead of just `parse`), the actual match includes both keyword characters (`\k`) and the period. There's one complication with that: The negative lookahead will latch onto the `log()` in `console.log()`, because the leading keyword boundary assertion (`\<`) matches there as well. We can disallow that match by also excluding a period just before the function; i.e. by placing `\.\@<!` in between:

```
\<\%(\%(if *\|console\.log\|function\)(\)\@!\.\@<!\(\k\|\.\)\+\>(.*)
```

That will highlight just the following calls:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage["beards"])
BLAH.blah.somefunc(arge, arg,arg);
foo.log(asdf)
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this only for VIM's flavour of regexp, or do other ones implement the \<\%(\) idea? Looks like VIM has a large set of special \% ... commands. The interactive regexr site I linked doesn't look like it recognizes these.

Comment: Perl (and PCRE) implement similar things ([`:help perl-patterns`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns)), but with different syntax. Java and .NET have most, too. Many other regexp dialects are not that powerful.